# I accidentally npm installed 'serv' instead of 'serve' (NPM install)

Tags: npm, npm-install, serve

I accidentally used "npm i -g serv" instead of "npm i -g serve".

Which installed the following package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serv

Is this safe to use? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

##### I looked into both packages, and both packages are look similar. But if you're accidentally installed `serv`, then why you using it. Go for `serve`, and it's the most popular (12,96,417/week downloads) when comparing in between them.

Or if you don't know how to uninstall it, just execute:-
`npm uninstall -g serv`
And install the `serve`:-
`npm install -g serve`

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't is it safe to use, rather, is it what I want to use. serv and serve are different packages, and serv may not be the one you want to use for your usecase, but it does not hurt to have both installed, you don't need to use both of them. Just install serve and it will work fine and serv will not interfere.